# SSD Partitioning for windows 10, ubuntu and data

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

My intention is to split my new SSD in three partitions:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Ubuntu 20.10
- Data shared between two OS

When I install W10 it automatically creates three primary partitions, Ubuntu another one so it is impossible to create Data partition neither with W10 "Disk Management" nor with Gparted because I already reached the maximum number of primary partitions.

Which is the best practice to divide the disk as I wish?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it before with Windows 7 and Debian. Debian had 2 primary partitions, same as Windows.
I had primary C: partition on windows, and logical partition mounted as D: for data (created on extended partition as seen from gparted when you're running Linux).
Linux can see and mount NTFS partition, just make sure it is mounted every time your Ubuntu boots.
So, the steps are: reduce the size of your partitions to create free space and then create extended partition, with logical NTFS partition. It will be visible from both Windows and Ubuntu.

Regardless of your problem, max number of primary partitions needed to have Windows and Linux is 3: 1 boot (used by both Win and Linux), 1 for Windows and 1 for Linux (root). Windows creates additional recovery partition, but it is not essential to have it. It can be safely deleted (if needed, you can start recovery from external disk, like USB, or DVD).
In that case, there is 1 primary partition left to be used as you like it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it tomorrow morning